# Find icon of running android processes

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Lets say I'm making a task killer, I would need to be able to

1. get the icons of all the current running processes
2. list it all in a `ListView`

I figured out how to find the name of all the running processes, but I cant seem to figure out how to get the icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PackageManager` can help you. It has a method called `GetApplicationIcon`, which takes a package name, which you should already have, and gives you an `ImageDrawable` back which you can load into whatever `View`.

I.e.:

```
var icon = PackageManager.GetApplicationIcon("com.example.someapp");
imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
```